# Are the halloween gifts account or soulbound?

Tags: guild-wars-2

How are the three gifts, [Gift of The Moon](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Gift_of_The_Moon), [Gift of Spiders](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Gift_of_Spiders) and [Gift of Souls](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Gift_of_Souls) bound?

Are the recipes bound as well when you get it from the Mystic Forge?

Comment: The three gifts are, at minimum, account bound. I don't know if they're bound when created, however, but I think they can also be found in ToT bags (and thus, sold on the TP).

Comment: People are selling the recipes on the TP, so they at least aren't soul/account bound (unless they are found in bags or something)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three gifts are account bound.